# Removing spaces in column data in Oracle 12.1 - SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

We are using Oracle based ERP and one of our column, has a specific rule which says that we have a several spaces in the begining and the end of each string. It looks something like this:

```
       A          |          B
--------------------------------------
   Value1         |123
   Value2         |345
```

There are 3 spaced in front and 9 spaces after each value in A column. I'm trying to extract the information using SQLPlus script:

```
SET colsep ,
SET pagesize 0
SET feedback OFF
SET heading OFF
SET trimspool ON
SET trimout ON
spool d:\spool.csv
select trim(rtrim(A)), B, from table;
spool out
```

The result is as follows:

```
Value1         ,123
Value2         ,345
```

What I need is:

```
Value1,123
Value2,345
```

Any idea how to achieve that?
Tried trim, rtrim, replace, regexp_replace but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Your datatype might be `char`. `varchar` will give you expexted result.

Comment: does this work?: select replace(a||','||b,' ','') from table;

Comment: what does this give you: select dump(A) from table;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
select replace(col1||','||col2,' ','') from your_table;
```

Example

```
SQL> create table test12(col1 char(10),col2 integer);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test12(col1,col2) values ('value1',1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test12(col1,col2) values ('value2',2);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select replace(col1||','||col2,' ','') from test12;
value1,1
value2,2
SQL> spool off;
SQL>
```

test.csv

```
SQL> select replace(col1||','||col2,' ','') from test12;
value1,1
value2,2
SQL> spool off;
```